# Calculating NDVI for small study area using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi

When I click on the field while doing NDVI analysis on the GEE platform, the graph is not generated. I  don't understand the reason for this. My study area is small.

Creating a chart when I try it on a large study area.

Do you have a solution?
And how can I add other analyses to the table at the bottom right?

My code is below:

```
var l8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_RT').filterBounds(geometry)
.map(function(image){return image.clip(geometry)}).filter (ee.Filter.lt ( 'CLOUD_COVER' , 5 ))
var styling = {color: 'red', fillColor: '00000000'};
Map.addLayer(geometry.style(styling));
Map.centerObject(geometry);
var cloudscore = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleCloudScore(l8);
var filtered = l8.filterBounds(geometry);

//NDVI
var rgb = l8.select(['B4', 'B3', 'B2']);
var filtered = l8.filterBounds(geometry);
function addNDVI(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']);
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
}


var cloudscore = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleCloudScore(l8);
var image = ee.Image(filtered.first());
var with_ndvi = filtered.map(addNDVI);
var greenest = with_ndvi.qualityMosaic('nd').float();
var vis = {min: 0, max: 1, palette: [
  'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'FCD163', '66A000', '207401',
  '056201', '004C00', '023B01', '012E01', '011301'
]};
//
var ndvi = l8.map(function(image) {
  return image.select().addBands(image.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']));
});
Map.addLayer(ndvi, vis, 'NDVI');

// NDVI grafiği
//NDWI
 
var rgb = l8.select(['B4', 'B3', 'B2']);
var ndwi = l8.map(function(image) {
  return image.select().addBands(image.normalizedDifference(['B6', 'B5']));
});

var vis = {min: 0, max: 1, palette: [
  'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'FCD163', '66A000', '207401',
  '056201', '004C00', '023B01', '012E01', '011301'
]};

//NDWI grafiği

var NDVI_STYLE = {
  min: 0,
  max: 1,
  palette: ["beb261","8ffff9","1cd810"]
};
var NDVI_VIS_MAX_VALUE = 1;
var NDVI_VIS_NONLINEARITY = 4;
var PARCEL_STYLE = {color: 'green', fillColor: '00000000'};
var HIGHLIGHT_STYLE = {color: 'red', fillColor: '00000000'};
function colorStretch(image) {
  return image.divide(NDVI_VIS_MAX_VALUE)
      .pow(1 / NDVI_VIS_NONLINEARITY);
}
function undoColorStretch(val) {
  return Math.pow(val, NDVI_VIS_NONLINEARITY) * NDVI_VIS_MAX_VALUE;
}
Map.addLayer(NM17, vis)
Map.addLayer(geometry.style(PARCEL_STYLE));
Map.style().set({cursor: 'crosshair'});

Map.add(ui.Label(
    'Trabzon Tarım Alanı Araştırması', {fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: '24px'}));

print(NM17)
print(NM14)

//Date slider for image collection
var start = ee.Image(with_ndvi.first()).date().get('year').format();
var now = Date.now();
var end = ee.Date(now).format();
// Run this function on a change of the dateSlider.
var rangeStart='2014-01-01'
var rangeEnd='2021-01-01'
var showMosaic = function(range) {
  rangeEnd = range.end()
  rangeStart = range.start()
  //var with_ndvi = filtered.map(addNDVI);
  //filtered.filterDate(range.start(), range.end())
  //with_ndvi = filtered.map(addNDVI);
  ///filtered = L8.filterBounds(NM).filterDate(range.start(),range.end());
  var mosaic = ({
    collection: l8.filterDate(range.start(), range.end())
  
  });
// Asynchronously compute the name of the composite.  Display it.
  range.start().get('year').evaluate(function(name) {
    var visParams = {bands: ['nd'], max: 100};
    var layer = ui.Map.Layer(NM17, vis, name + ' composite');
    Map.layers().set(0, layer);
  });
};

// Asynchronously compute the date range and show the slider.
var dateRange = ee.DateRange(start, end).evaluate(function(range) {
  var dateSlider = ui.DateSlider({
    start: range['dates'][0],
    end: range['dates'][1],
    value: null,
    period: 365,
    onChange: showMosaic
  });
print(range)
  Map.add(dateSlider.setValue(now));
});


//// sağ alt panel
// kullanıcının tıkladığı nokta
var selectedPoints = [];
// seçilen orman listesi döndürülür
function getSelectedParcels() {
  return geometry.filterBounds(ee.Geometry.MultiPoint(selectedPoints));
}
function makeResultsBarChart(parcels) {
  print(rangeStart.format('Y'))
  var newstart=rangeStart.format('Y-01-01')
  var newend=rangeStart.advance(1,'year').format('Y-01-01')
  print(newend)
  //print(rangeEnd)
  //with_ndvi.filterDate(rangeStart,rangeEnd)
  //with_ndvi=with_ndvi.set("date_range", [1514764800000,1546300800000])
  
  var filtered = l8.filterBounds(geometry).filterDate(newstart,newend);
  var image = ee.Image(filtered.first());
  var with_ndvi = filtered.map(addNDVI);
  var median = with_ndvi.reduce(ee.Reducer.median());
  print(with_ndvi)
  var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: with_ndvi.select('nd'),
  region: geometry,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 500
});
 chart.style().set({stretch: 'both'});
  return chart;
}

function makeResultsTable(geometry) {
  var table = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(geometry, 'Name');
  table.setChartType('Table');
  table.setOptions({allowHtml: true, pageSize: 5});
  table.style().set({stretch: 'both'});
  return table;
}
function updateOverlay() {
  var overlay = getSelectedParcels().style(HIGHLIGHT_STYLE);
  Map.layers().set(2, ui.Map.Layer(overlay));
}
function updateChart() {
  var chartBuilder = chartTypeToggleButton.value;
  var chart = chartBuilder(getSelectedParcels());
  resultsPanel.clear().add(chart).add(buttonPanel);
}
function clearResults() {
  selectedPoints = [];
  Map.layers().remove(Map.layers().get(2));
  var instructionsLabel = ui.Label('İndeks karşılaştırmak için bölge seçiniz');
  resultsPanel.widgets().reset([instructionsLabel]);
}
function handleMapClick(location) {
  selectedPoints.push([location.lon, location.lat]);
  updateOverlay();
  updateChart();
}
Map.onClick(handleMapClick);


function ToggleButton(states, onClick) {
  var index = 0;
  var button = ui.Button(states[index].label);
  button.value = states[index].value;
  button.onClick(function() {
    index = ++index % states.length;
    button.setLabel(states[index].label);
    button.value = states[index].value;
    onClick();
  });
  return button;
}
var chartTypeToggleButton = ToggleButton(
    [
      {
        label: 'Seçilen Bölge Özelliklerini Göster',
        value: makeResultsBarChart,
      },
      {
        label: 'Sonuçları grafik olarak göster',
        value: makeResultsTable,
      }
    ],
    updateChart);
    var buttonPanel = ui.Panel(
    [ui.Button('Clear results', clearResults), chartTypeToggleButton],
    ui.Panel.Layout.Flow('horizontal'), {margin: '0 0 0 auto', width: '500px'});

var resultsPanel = ui.Panel({style: {position: 'bottom-right'}});
Map.add(resultsPanel);
clearResults();
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Faykanbayram%2FShapefile%3ADeneme2

Comment: Cannot load repository. Repository "users/aykanbayram/Shapefile" does not exist.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: Your code works on my feature collection, please check the line:   var table = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(geometry, 'Name'); and name field exists on your feature collection as property of your geometry variable